# How to use Transform.multiply4x4 in famous?

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I'm trying to use Transform.multiply4x4() to move a surface modifier but it doesn't seem to work as expect. I am trying to rotate a surface almost flat and then send it off into the distance. 
My code looks like this

```
       myModifier.setTransform(
            Transform.multiply4x4(
                Transform.rotateX(1.4), //rotate at the same time by 1.4 radians on the x axis 
                Transform.scale(0, 0, 1) //send back into the distance 
            ),
            {duration: 600}
        );
```

However the only thing that happens is that the surface that is attached to the modifier just gets pushed back into the distance there is no rotation on the X axis. Am I using the `multiplyx4x` method wrong ?
I am not trying to stagger the effects I am actually trying to do them at the same time.

Comment: When you say rotate almost flat, what do you mean?

Comment: about 80 degrees because if I make it 90 degrees it is flat and then you can't see it because it would be like looking at a piece of paper only on the edge.

Comment: Ok, I will post what I think you are trying to do in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to chain your modifiers instead.

**[See this example jsBin](http://jsbin.com/rudufu/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
  var myRotateModifier = new Modifier({    
    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
    align: [0.5, 0.5],
  });
  myRotateModifier.setTransform(
    Transform.rotateX(1.4),
    {duration: 1000}
  );

  var myModifier = new Modifier();
  myModifier.setTransform(
    Transform.scale(0, 0, 1),
    {duration: 2000}
  );

  mainContext.add(myRotateModifier).add(myModifier).add(surface);
```

#### Why not the multiply4x4 in this case

The `multiply4x4` gives you a result matrix from multiplying the two transforms then applies that matrix transform. It results in what you are seeing in your code.

Comment: Yeah I have done it this way before but was more interested in doing it with the Transform.multiply4x4 method. I have it working with chaining but again I'd like to see it done with Transform.multiply4x4.

Comment: https://famo.us/docs/modifiers/StateModifier would be a bit cleaner than chaining modifiers, simply call modifier.setRotate and modifier.setScale and you won't need a second modifier. I have not used 4x4 yet and I'd be willing to look into it, but I think a StateModifier would be easiest to read for others looking at your code (or you looking at it next year)

Comment: @Stephan Bijzitter Im going to try that method as well it might just be easier

Comment: Thanks @edgar-martinez , good question to help clear up for those needing to understand the Transform.